# Why can't I add a single Ellipse (patch) to more than one axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why do I need a new instance of a patch for each axis I'm going to add it to? When does the patch depend on an axis, and why can't the mathematical definition be added to different axes to be drawn more than once? Is the `oneEllipse` the efficient way to deal with this?

If the Ellipse is an artist on the current axis (if otherwise unspecified), why can I add `f, g` below to different axes when they were created with the same current axis?

```
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

x, y, width, height, angle=10.0, 6.0, 7.0, 3.0, 160.0

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

def oneEllipse():
    return Ellipse(xy=(x,y), width=height, height=width, angle=angle,
            facecolor='blue')

e = Ellipse(xy=(x,y), width=width, height=height, angle=angle,
            facecolor='black')

f = Ellipse(xy=(x+2,y+2), width=width, height=height, angle=angle,
            facecolor='green')
g = Ellipse(xy=(x+2,y+2), width=width, height=height, angle=angle,
            facecolor='green')


#ax1.add_artist(e) # Can use e only once --
ax2.add_artist(e) # if added twice, appears on neither axis
                  # whether called in loop or not

ax1.add_artist(f) # These were defined with the same gca(), weren't they?
ax2.add_artist(g) # Why not the same behavior as e?

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set(xlim=(0,20), ylim=(0,10))
    ax.add_artist(oneEllipse()) # Generating a new Ellipse each time, fine
    ax.add_artist(e) # if e was added to the last axis in the loop *only*,
                     # it appears if in loop
```

[image]

Edited to add: duplicate of [Adding the same Patch instance to multiple subplots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638546/adding-the-same-patch-instance-to-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib) but with more examples of what fails how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is because you can't.

The slightly longer answer is that as part of the drawing process the artists need to know what `Axes` they belong to due to the way the transform stack works.  Going into much more detail would require digging into the full draw/transform stack.

In the next feature release of mpl (2.1 ~summer 2015) trying to do this will raise an exception (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3835)

Also, be careful about `Axis` vs `Axes` ([see diagram](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure))

Comment: Well, that's pythic. (Am I confusing `Axes` and `Axis` the code-objects, or just using axes-the-English-plural-of-axis ambiguously?)

Comment: Due to the naming of `Axes` vs `Axis` in the code I sacrifice english to be clear about the code ;)